# Creating S3 Files in a Loop - Node.JS + AWS-SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a set of files from their binary data received from an API call but the files are never created, but the promise.then function is called:

```
for(var i in fileSections){
    var content = fileSections[i].split((/Content-Length: [0-9]*/));
    var fileName = content[0].split('filename=')[1].trim();
    var file = {Bucket : 'MyBucket', Key: ROOT+'/'+FOLDER+'/'+SUBFOLDER+'/'+fileName, Body: content[1]};
    console.log('Creating file: '+file.Key );
***CODE RUNS TO AT LEAST HERE FOR EACH FILE***
    promises.push(S3.upload(file));
}
***.THEN FUNCTION FIRES***
Promise.all(promises).then(confirmProposal()).catch(function(err){context.done(err);});
```

Earlier on in the process I create a file in S3 using this code:

```
var application = {Bucket : 'MyBucket', Key: ROOT+'/'+FOLDER+'/'+SUBFOLDER+'/application.xml', Body: fileSections[0]};
S3.upload(application,function(err,data)
    {
        ...files are created in here on a successful response ...
    });
```

Which works and the file is created. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
promises.push(S3.upload(file));
```

to this:

```
promises.push(S3.upload(file).promise());
```

The AWS NodeJS SDK functions don't return a promise directly. For example the `S3.upload()` function returns an `AWS.S3.ManagedUpload` object. You have to call `.promise()` on the returned object to get a promise.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks!